# Multiprocess line generation, but plotting in main

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiprocessing

I have a list of trajectories (various lengths) which I want to (overlay) plot on the same figure and then show/save it.
This can be done by running a simple for loop and calling `plt.plot()` for each trajectory, and in the end running `plt.show()`.

(using `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`)

This is very slow for a large number of trajectories (>10k) so I would like to parallelize the plots, but still have one single plot in the end.

I have found several [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51409295/multiprocess-plotting-in-matplotlib) that achieve this but making plots in each process. However, this is not what I need, as the trajectories all need to be in one figure.

I have also tried implementing a following approach:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import multiprocessing as mpi

class WorkerClass():
    def __init__(self, ax):
        self.ax = ax

    def worker(self, tli):
        t,l,i = tli
        self.ax.plot(t[:,0], t[:,1], alpha=0.5, color='C0' if l==-1 else 'C1', linestyle=np.array(['-','-.',':','--',':'])[i.astype(bool)][0])

    def get_ax(self):
        return self.ax


### main code
# trajectories, labels, info are lists passed from other functions

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
w = Worker(ax)

with mpi.Pool(processes=4) as p:
        lines = p.map(w.worker, zip(trajectories, labels, info))

ax = w.get_ax()
ax.set_title('Trajectories')
plt.show()
```

However this doesn't work, I get a stack error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/robin/anaconda3/envs/py35lab/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/robin/anaconda3/envs/py35lab/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/robin/anaconda3/envs/py35lab/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 429, in _handle_results
    task = get()
  File "/home/robin/anaconda3/envs/py35lab/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 251, in recv
    return ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
  File "/home/robin/anaconda3/envs/py35lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1904, in __setstate__
    mgr = plt._backend_mod.new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, self)
  File "/home/robin/anaconda3/envs/py35lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 1044, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    window = Tk.Tk(className="matplotlib")
  File "/home/robin/anaconda3/envs/py35lab/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1868, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: out of stack space (infinite loop?)
```

Comment: You do not need the `get_ax` method in your worker class.

Comment: What makes your code slow is the drawing of the end result, not adding the line. The drawing needs to happen in exactly one single process, so you would gain close to nothing when using multiprocessing - even if it worked.

Comment: Hopefully OP does not automatically draw the graph for each `ax.plot` call.

Comment: Stepping back a bit... drawing many lines on a single axes is easily speed up by using one single `LineCollection` instead of multiple `plot` calls.